# Formally prove that the following two premises are contradictory

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a Proof and Logic paper coming up in a few days and I'm systematically working through papers. I have been using a software called Fitch and mostly constructing formal proofs using Proof by Cases

> Question states in Fitch bar format:
>
> A ∧ B,
> ∼A ∧ ∼B

Please see below for my workings:
[image]

So everything checks out but what I'm a little weary of is the fact that my ⊥ is  not sitting in the main bar as the final goal of my proof. i.e. inline with A ∧ B and ∼A ∧ ∼B which makes me wonder if I need to go further?

The only way I could think to do this was to Assume A ∨ B and then from there derive a contradiction for each atomic sentence A and B and finally resolve the proof using disjunctive elimination.

Could someone perhaps just peruse this for me and let me know if I am in fact on the right track.

Prior to wanting to use A ∨ B as an assumption in line 3 I thought perhaps De Morgan's Theorem so I could push the negation outwards and derive ~(A ∨ B) but the proof didn't check out this way.

Thanks for taking the time to review.

Comment: The final $\bot$ in your proof is not in the "right place" because what you have proved is a contradiction from 2 and the additonal *assumption* $A \lor B$. Thus, $\bot$ depends on $A \lor B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that the two premises are *contradictory*, you have to derive $\bot$ from them :

1) $A \land B$ --- premise

2) $\lnot A \land \lnot B$ --- premise

3) $A$ --- from 1) by $\land$-elimination

4) $\lnot A$ --- from 2) by $\land$-elimination

> 5) $\bot$ --- from 3) and 4).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. So then is it enough to prove A and ~A contradictory without looking considering B?

Comment: This makes sense though... I suppose as long as I am proving that the premises are contradictory I could user either A or B? There I go overthinking things again. This is weighted 6 marks in the exam paper. That's why I thought I needed to go off on a tangent here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Metastasis - of course, there is a "symmetry" in the premises between $A$ and $B$; thus you can attain the same result with $B$ and $\lnot B$ without considering $A$.